# keyboard pushes up the divs on mobile views with React

Tags: ios, reactjs, css, mobile

I have this message thread component that has a header, content and a textarea and everytime. The issue here is in mobile views, when I want to type a message the keyboard on IOS (Iphones) pushes the divs up so the header would be hidden, I don't want this behavior, for Android it doesn't behave like this. This app is using React and scss and the code is this:

```
<div className="message-thread-wrapper d-flex flex-column">
               <div className="messages-header d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                   <Icon
                       className="back-btn d-lg-none"
                       icon="chevron-left"
                       onClick={(e) => {
                           e.stopPropagation();
                           actions.closeMessage();
                       }}
                   />
                   <h5 className="messages-title text-truncate">
                       {participant.firstname && participant.lastname ? `${participant.firstname} ${participant.lastname}` : participant.name}
                   </h5>
                   <div className="messages-header-right d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                       <Icon
                           className="settings-btn"
                           icon="settings"
                           onClick={(e) => {
                               e.stopPropagation();
                               this.toggleDeleteMenu();
                           }}
                       />
                       }
                       <Icon
                           className="close-btn-cross d-none d-lg-block"
                           icon="cross"
                           onClick={(e) => {
                               e.stopPropagation();
                               this.setState(
                                   {isMinimized: false},
                                   actions.closeMessage
                               );
                           }}
                       />
                   </div>
               </div>
               {showDeleteMenu &&
               <DeleteMenu onClick={this.archiveMessage} onClickOutside={this.toggleDeleteMenu}/>
               }
               {
                   this.renderMessages()
               }
               <div
                   className="bottom-actions d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
                   <TextArea
                       ref={ref => this.messageInput = ref}
                       className="input blue d-block"
                       name="msgText"
                       placeholder="Type your message..."
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       .
                       autoFocus
                   />
                   <Button
                       className={`send-btn circle ${IS_SAFARI ? 'safari-fix-button' : ''}`}
                       icon="paper-plane"
                       onClick={this.onSendMessage}
                   />
               </div>
               }
           </div>
```

and the scss file:

```
.message-thread-wrapper {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0;
z-index: 950;

.messages-header {
    padding: 19px 16px 14px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 57px;
    color: white;
    pointer-events: none;
    position:sticky;

    .back-btn {
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .close-btn-cross {
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }

    .settings-btn {
        width: 25px;
        height: 26px;
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
}

.delete-menu {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    .menu-arrow {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: white;
        border-right: none;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    a {
        padding: 18px;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-decoration: none;
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.messages-content {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    .dateline {
        margin: 28px 0 11px 0;
        line-height: 1.33;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.bottom-actions {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 130px;
    min-height: 70px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px 0 #d9dbdc;

    .form-group-wrapper {
        padding-top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        align-self: stretch;
        overflow: auto;

        &.text-area-wrapper {
            padding-right: 71px;

            textarea {
                min-height: 48px;
            }

            .form-bar {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }

    .button.circle {
        width: 34px;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 9px 12px 9px 8px;
        position: fixed;
        right: 26px;

        &.safari-fix-button {
            bottom: 22px;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Note I deleted the properties that are not important for this question so it won't be too long.

This is how it currently behaves:

- Iphone:
  [image: Iphone view with keyboard]
- Android - Pixel 2XL:
  [image: Android view with keyboard]

I would appreciate if Any could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue but still haven't found a fix.